# Apache and ldap authentication for extenernal IP only

Tags: apache, ldap

is there a way in Apache, when using the mod_authnz_ldap module, to only have it ask for a login if the IP address is not within a defined, internal range? We have a site that we don't want people to have to log in from when they are in the office but when out of the office - from home or mobile etc they should have to authenticate.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.
Asuming you use the LDAP authorization on a per Location basis:

```
<Location /your/path/here>
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 192.168.0.

     Auth...
     <your complete ldap config here>

     # if one of the above matches, go on
     Satisfy any
</Location>
```

You can find the complete documentation for satisfy [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy)